# python csv.dictreader not working with a data.gov csv

Tags: python, csv

Using some random CSV data from data.gov, for example:  "Gravesite locations of Veterans and beneficiaries in HAWAII, as of January 2011" http://www.data.gov/raw/4608 I am trying to parse the CSV with python and process each row:

```
randomData = csv.DictReader(open('/downloads/ngl_hawaii.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",")
     for row in randomData:
         print row
```

The sample CSV data:

> d_first_name,d_mid_name,d_last_name,d_suffix,d_birth_date,d_death_date,section_id,row_num,site_num,cem_name,cem_addr_one,cem_addr_two,city,state,zip,cem_url,cem_phone,relationship,v_first_name,v_mid_name,v_last_name,v_suffix,branch,rank,war
>
> Joe,"E","JoJo","","10/02/1920","03/12/2000","100-E","","3","HAWAII
>   STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA
>   HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","111444","","SXXXXX","Veteran
>   (Self)","Joe","E","JoJo","","US
>   ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR II"

The result is not overly pretty (printing one row):

> {'v_last_name': None, 'cem_addr_two':
>   None, 'rank': None, 'd_suffix': None,
>   'city': None, 'row_num': None, 'zip':
>   None, 'cem_phone': None,
>   'd_last_name': None, e,
>   'd_first_name':
>   'Joe,"E","JoJo","","10/02/1920","03/12/2000","100-E","","3","HAWAII
>   STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA
>   HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","11144
>   "SXXXXX","","US ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR
>   II"', 'war': None, 'v_mid_name': None,
>   'cem_url': None, 'cem_name': None,
>   'relationship': None, 'v_first_name':
>   None, 'se one, 'cem_addr_one': None,
>   'd_birth_date': None, 'd_death_date':
>   None}

As you can see, the header fields (first line in the csv) aren't properly being associated to each subsequent row.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the CSV quality poor?

**Thanks to Casey for asking if I've opened the file up in another program.  Excel messed up the file....**

Comment: And the CSV input looks exactly how? Should we guess what's wrong with your csv parameters without knowing how the input looks like?

Comment: Sentinel, the CSV is located at http://www.data.gov/raw/4608 -- thought it was obvious.

Comment: @sdolgy - better than letting other SO users (how many of them would like to help you?) download the whole 18.8MB file, post the first 2-3 lines and format it properly as a code within your question.

Comment: What version of Python on which operating system?

Comment: our favorite windows ... Python 2.7 .. @eumiro goodp point

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.1 on Ubuntu and it works as expected below. I'll try it on windows too.

Comment: I just ran the same thing I posted in my answer on Windows 7, with python 2.7.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: @sdolgy: "Excel messed up the file" ... very dubious conclusion; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the original file, which I downloaded [here](http://www.data.gov/download/4608/csv), it is valid CSV. I mistook the output from your script.

Since your using the csv.DictReader each row is turned into a Dictionary with the header values as keys and the data for each as values. I ran it on the same file and it looks like everything is matched up correctly, although I didn't go through the entire thing.

According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

`class csv.DictReader(csvfile[, fieldnames=None[, restkey=None[, restval=None[, dialect='excel'[, *args, **kwds]]]]])`

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader
>   but maps the information read into a
>   dict whose keys are given by the
>   optional fieldnames parameter. If the
>   fieldnames parameter is omitted, the
>   values in the first row of the csvfile
>   will be used as the fieldnames. If the
>   row read has more fields than the
>   fieldnames sequence, the remaining
>   data is added as a sequence keyed by
>   the value of restkey. If the row read
>   has fewer fields than the fieldnames
>   sequence, the remaining keys take the
>   value of the optional restval
>   parameter. Any other optional or
>   keyword arguments are passed to the
>   underlying reader instance.

If this isn't the format you want it in, you might want to try the csv.reader which will just return a list for each row and not associate it with the headers.

To use the above DictReader, this is probably what you want:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('ngl_hawaii.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=','))
for row in reader:
    print row['d_first_name']
    print row['d_last_name']
```

Comment: I assure you the source data is a csv file and is not JSON.

Comment: thanks for following up.  so when i run it on the first five lines of the file, i get the garbage output above.  did you use my exact code?  This is with Python 2.7

Comment: The output above is not garbage. It is the raw output of a python dictionary. I'll update my post above.

Comment: right.  my understanding is that row[v_first_name] would equal the first CSV value of that row ... as v_first_name is the first header value.

Comment: row[v_first_name] would give you the resulting value in that row that matches up with that header. Not necessarily the first value of the row.

Comment: How does this change from the code I have put?  You have ',' instead of "," ... the result is when i write print row['d_first_name'] i get the full row printed and not just the one key/val ...

Comment: Your original code above you are just using print row. Which will print the entire dictionary. Are you saying that you are using the code I posted and it is still not working?

Comment: correct. using the print row['d_first_name'] prints out the full row.  if i `print row['d_last_name']` the result is `None`

Comment: Are you sure the file didn't get messed up somehow after you downloaded it? Did you happen to open it in something that would cause the formatting to change?

Comment: you mean, opening it in excel could cause it to go bozo?  ;)  hmmmm

Comment: yeah, it could if you opened it and than saved it. I always make a point to use something like Notepad++ when opening csv type files

Comment: @Casey: opening it with a text editor, mucking about, and saving it is much more likely to make it go bozo; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Strange, I get different output from you.

**data.csv:**

`d_first_name,d_mid_name,d_last_name,d_suffix,d_birth_date,d_death_date,section_id,row_num,site_num,cem_name,cem_addr_one,cem_addr_two,city,state,zip,cem_url,cem_phone,relationship,v_first_name,v_mid_name,v_last_name,v_suffix,branch,rank,war
"Emil","E","Seibel","","10/02/1920","03/12/2010","139-E","","3","HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","96744","","808-233-3630","Veteran (Self)","Emil","E","Seibel","","US ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR II",`

**Script:**

```
for line in csv.DictReader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=","):
    print line
```

**Output:**

```
{'v_last_name': 'Seibel', None: [''], 'cem_addr_two': '', 'rank': 'SGT', 'd_suffix': '', 'city': 'KANEOHE', 'row_num': '', 'zip': '96744', 'cem_phone': '808-233-3630', 'd_
last_name': 'Seibel', 'd_mid_name': 'E', 'state': 'HI', 'branch': 'US ARMY', 'd_first_name': 'Emil', 'war': 'WORLD WAR II', 'v_mid_name': 'E', 'cem_url': '', 'cem_name': '
HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY', 'relationship': 'Veteran (Self)', 'v_first_name': 'Emil', 'section_id': '139-E', 'v_suffix': '', 'site_num': '3', 'cem_addr_one': 'KAMEHAM
EHA HIGHWAY', 'd_birth_date': '10/02/1920', 'd_death_date': '03/12/2010'}
```

`csv.DictReader` is supposed to automatically get the field names from the first row in the file is the `fieldnames` parameter is ommited, [as described in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

The `None: ['']` in the output is caused by the trailing comma on each line of data.

**Working code example:**

### http://codepad.org/HdBhr4La

Comment: Can you give the exact link to the file that you used? I downloaded the csv file from his link above, and it is all working as expected.

Comment: I took the first two lines from the csv, so the header line and a line of data. http://pastie.org/1860382  .. when you say it works as expected, does it differ from my output in any way?

Comment: Doh, so excel was messing up the file for you? If in doubt, open it in a programmer's text editor and see what the data looks like.

Comment: +1 for noticing the extra comma on the end of the data lines. However see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this and it works fine with your file (renamed to foo)

```
import csv

ifile  = open('foo.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    # Save header row.
    if rownum == 0:
        header = row
    else:
        colnum = 0
        for col in row:
            print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col)
            colnum += 1

    rownum += 1

ifile.close()
```

**OUTPUT=**

```
d_first_name: Emil
d_mid_name: E
d_last_name: Seibel
d_suffix: 
d_birth_date: 10/02/1920
d_death_date: 03/12/2010
section_id: 139-E
row_num : 
site_num: 3
cem_name: HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY
cem_addr_one: KAMEHAMEHA HIGHWAY
cem_addr_two: 
city    : KANEOHE
state   : HI
zip     : 96744
cem_url : 
cem_phone: 808-233-3630
relationship: Veteran (Self)
v_first_name: Emil
v_mid_name: E
v_last_name: Seibel
v_suffix: 
branch  : US ARMY
rank    : SGT
war     : WORLD WAR II
```

Comment: It is delimited only by commas, with all strings quoted.

Comment: The output he has above is the output of the row object which is a python dictionary, that's why it is formatted the way it is.

Comment: I'm not sure we're  disagreeing. Either way, we've shown him two proofs that the files is sound and it's his code that needs altered, which was the original question. And Acorn has demonstrated that python will allow you to do things in overly complicated ways.

Comment: SnobOverflow .. the code wasn't faulty.  The underlying content was altered by excel and causing the problems.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) The reported result appears to have been butchered.**

Purportedly the result of printing a Python dictionary, it should be capable of being parsed back to a dictionary by Python. Not so; here it is with deletions necessary to get Python to parse it:

```
d = {'v_last_name': None, 'cem_addr_two': None, 'rank': None,
 'd_suffix': None, 'city': None, 'row_num': None, 'zip': None,
 'cem_phone': None, 'd_last_name': None,
 # e,
 'd_first_name': 'Joe,"E","JoJo","","10/02/1920","03/12/2000","100-E","","3","HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","11144 "SXXXXX","","US ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR II"',
 'war': None, 'v_mid_name': None, 'cem_url': None, 'cem_name': None,
 'relationship': None, 'v_first_name': None,
 # 'se one,
 'cem_addr_one': None, 'd_birth_date': None, 'd_death_date': None}
```

Compared with the heading line of the actual data file, the following column headings are missing:

```
'section_id', 'v_suffix', 'd_mid_name', 'state', 'branch', 'site_num'
```

**(2) The reported first data line appears to be an edited version of the actual first data line.**

```
reported: Joe,   "E","JoJo",  "","10/02/1920","03/12/2000","100-E","","3","HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","111444","","SXXXXX",      "Veteran (Self)","Joe", "E","JoJo",  "","US ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR II" 
actual  : "Emil","E","Seibel","","10/02/1920","03/12/2010","139-E","","3","HAWAII STATE VETERANS CEMETERY","KAMEHAMEHA HIGHWAY","","KANEOHE","HI","96744", "","808-233-3630","Veteran (Self)","Emil","E","Seibel","","US ARMY","SGT","WORLD WAR II",
changed : xxxxxx      xxxxxx                           x     xx                                                                                    xxxxxx      xxxxxxxxxxxx                    xxxx       xxxxxx                                   x
```

As noted by @Acorn, there is a superflous comma at the end of each actual data line. Also note that the first reported field is not quoted.

**(3) The reported data appears NOT to be the result of opening the file with Excel followed by saving as csv.**

Excel does only minimal quoting when saving as csv i.e. a field is quoted only if necessary. Experimentation shows no quotes in the first data line. The second data line ends in `US MARINE CORPS,GYSGT,"KOREA, VIETNAM"` ... quotes being necessitated by the embedded comma.

**(4) Further analysis of the reported result**

Ignoring the the butchery noted in (1) above, the reported dictionary has some interesting features:

(a) The reported dictionary has most of the expected keys, so it's a reasonable conclusion that csv.DictReader managed to parse the heading line OK.

(b) The key `d_first_name` (i) is the first in the heading line (ii) has a value that is the unsplit whole of the reported first data line. All of the other keys have value `None`.

This is consistent with the heading line using the same **non-comma** delimiter as DictReader, but the first data line using a **comma** delimiter. Note that the reported code has `delimiter=","` which is (i) unnecessary -- it's the default -- and (ii) **not** consistent with the reported result.

**Conclusion** Blaming Excel appears to be unjustified.

Comment: Wow! That's quite some analysis! I didn't notice the sample data the OP was using wasn't actual data from the file.. tampering has occurred and Excel has been framed! How did you manage to butcher the output as well OP? :)

Comment: glad you had some spare time john. thanks. the sample data i posted was modified as you showed in (2) on purpose out of respect. i am using the sample data for statistics and wasn't keen on posting the real names of fallen people. which is why the original xls was referenced.  ultimately, i had copied the original xls to another and removed all but the first five lines and saved it.  but this was done in excel and not in notepad ... and therein lay my problem.  all in all, SO helped me find the fault in my ways...

Comment: @sdolgy: (1) You should have included dummy data with your question. (2) You didn't state in your question that you were using dummy data. (3) You didn't refer to an xls file, you only mentioned CSV. (4) **I maintain my assertion that Excel would not botch up the data in the fashion you indicated.** Somehow you have managed to get delimiters in the heading record that are not the same as the delimiters in the first data line.